# Use Fermat’s little theorem to prove that $7\mid 2222^{5555}+5555^{2222}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Use Fermat’s little theorem to prove that $2222^{5555}+5555^{2222}$ is a multiple of $7$.

First, by using Fermat’s little theorem we have
$$5555^{2222}=5555^{6\times 370+2}\equiv 5555^2\pmod 7$$
and
$$2222^{5555}=2222^{6\times 925+5}\equiv 2222^5\pmod 7.$$
Therefore
$$5555^{2222}+2222^{5555}\equiv 5555^2+2222^5\pmod 7$$
And I’m stuck from here.

Comment: What is $5555\pmod 7$ and $2222\pmod 7$? And - how can you use that?

Comment: i.e. by the [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)  $\bmod 7\!:\,\ a^n \equiv (a\bmod 7)^n\ \ $